# When applying to grad school: GPA vs Prestige

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate, gpa, ranking

For undergraduate studies is it preferable to go the a prestigious school and get decent GPA or to go to not well known school but be top of the class?

Comment: While I'm sure there is a reasonable answer to this, i'm not sure this should be a question asked when thinking about where to apply (or go to) undergraduate school: the person/scholar you will become will matter much more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for US Ph.D. programs, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-us-ph-d-programs-particularly-for-wea)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, when I'm reading applications I barely notice either one. I don't have to look at GPA 99 times out of 100 because those below the minimum are screened out, and I don't care much about what school you went to because prestige schools have some crappy departments and low-prestige schools have some great ones, and I'm almost never going to know which is which.

I spend most of my app-reading time on the personal statement. Can you write? (Very important in my department; importance to others is obviously somewhat variable.) Can you tech? (Likewise.) Do you understand what you're getting yourself into, and have decent, non-clichéd, at least marginally realistic reasons you're doing it? Do you have skills or an educational or life background we're specifically looking to recruit? Relevant experience?

Go be a worthwhile person with a clue. That's what we're looking to admit, not shiny GPAs or fancy-schmantzy schools.